# Xamarin Facebook Log in and use Graph api

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin

if you know guys
I want to connect to **facebook** with my android app on **xamarin**,but i have problem i can't get hash key,in **.android** folder there is no **debug.keystore** file,if can show me some code or video how connect to **facebook** please help

Comment: you need to rephrase your question, it is not clear. Also you should consult both Facebook documentation and Xamarin's facebook SDK component both have *getting started* tutorials for you to learn from

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

use password **android**.

Answer (score 0):

question is not clear as Alex said. However this video is helpful which used Graph api for log in to facebook. I tried and it works and it also have github link for code.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGW9Q4atJNc

Comment: Can you please post a summary? If the video is taken offline for any reason your answer becomes useless otherwise.

Comment: Here is the github link of code from Houssem. I'll make a short summary. https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Facebook-Login-Xamarin-Forms